# How do I add a value to a field without erasing and repeating?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So that's what I have. For example, a field contains six letters:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F
```

Ok. Now I want to update this field and add the letter `G`. I can use this script:

```
declare
   v_c pls_integer;
   v_s varchar(7) := 'LETTERS';
begin
   select 1 into v_c from some_table where lower(some_column_name) = lower(v_s);
   if (v_c = 1) then
      execute immediate 'update some_table set values = ''A,B,C,D,E,F,G''
         where lower(some_column_name) = lower('''||v_s||''')';
      commit;
   end if;
end;
/
```

But I need to check. This field may already contain some letters. Perhaps this letter is already in this list. For example, the letter `C`. If the letter already exists, then don't add it. If there is no such letter, just add it to the end (separated by commas). How can I do this?

Comment: What if you have `A,B,C,F`  and you need to add `E`?

Comment: Just add to the end..

Comment: well.. it needs to be said - this is a bad normalization.  you would be able to easily do this with a unique constraint and simple inserts if normalized correctly.

Comment: Yes, I agree) But this is what exists now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just want another condition in the where clause:

```
where ',' || values || ',' not like '%,' || v_s || ',%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just append it to the list of existing letters.

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE test_letters
(
    letters    VARCHAR2 (50)
);

insert into test_letters
SELECT 'A, B, C, D' AS letters FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A, B, C, D, E, F' AS letters FROM DUAL;
```

#### Update

```
UPDATE test_letters
   SET letters = letters || ', G'
 WHERE letters not like '%G%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651) function, which may perform better than LIKE or Reg exp.

```
update test_letters
   set letters = letters || ', G'
 where instr(letters,'G') = 0;
```